# MT5 machine learning model for paraphrasing

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I'm trying to create a machine learning model to paraphrase given Persian text. I was introduced to mt5 as a multilingual text-to-text model. However, I can't figure out how to implement this. I have gathered the data. Here's a sample of the data:
[Data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz6MC.jpg)

**---UPDATE---**

I have tried to paraphrase using the T5 model, and it works well for English. However, I can't get logical results from the MT5 model. Here is the T5 version code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Vamsi/T5_Paraphrase_Paws")
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("Vamsi/T5_Paraphrase_Paws")
```

```
sentence = sentence_1

text =  "paraphrase: " + sentence + " </s>"

encoding = tokenizer.encode_plus(text,pad_to_max_length=True, return_tensors="pt")
input_ids, attention_masks = encoding["input_ids"], encoding["attention_mask"]


outputs = model.generate(
    input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_masks,
    max_length=256,
    do_sample=True,
    top_k=120,
    top_p=0.95,
    early_stopping=False,
    num_return_sequences=5
)

print ("\n")
print("Origianl sentence:")
print(sentence)
print ("\n")
print("Paraphrasing:")

for output in outputs:
    line = tokenizer.decode(output, skip_special_tokens=True,clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True)
    print(line)
```

When I give the following sentence to the model, it returns the following results:

*Original sentence:*

- Washing your hands Properly will keep you away from COVID-19.

*Paraphrasing:*

- By properly washing your hands, you will keep away from COVID-19.
- Washing your hands correctly will keep you away from COVID-19.
- Washing your hands correctly will keep you away from COVID-19.
- Washing your hands correctly will keep you from COVID-19.
- Washing your hands properly will keep you away from COVID-19.

But when I change the model to the MT5-base, the results are absurd. Here is an example:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/mt5-base")
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("google/mt5-base")
```

*Original sentence:*

- Washing your hands Properly will keep you away from COVID-19.

*Paraphrasing:*

- <extra_id_0>, left.
- <extra_id_0>, also.
- <extra_id_0>. Comment
- <extra_id_0>.
- <extra_id_0>o.

Comment: Please [don't post code/errors/data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).  "How to solve this problem with code" is not [on topic for StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Try to [make an honest attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) at solving the problem yourself, and then feel free to ask specific questions about your solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is a valid question. After the update, it provides all the information needed to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO mT5 can't be used for paraphrase generation out-of-the-box, just like the T5 can. You can find fine-tuned versions of the T5 model intended for paraphrase generation on the HuggingFace Hub, such as [this one](https://huggingface.co/secometo/mt5-base-turkish-question-paraphrase-generator). There's a paper associated with the model and you may find the solution there. As far as I understand it, you need a labeled dataset with which you will fine-tune the T5 model to generate paraphrases in your language.